# How to upload file using Multer from child object

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have a User object in my application, where each user Object has a Nominee as a child object With a File field name photo.

### JSON Object

```js
{
   name: 'Jhon Doe',
   phone: '01548761645',
   email: 'jhon@email.com',
   photo: File(),
   nominee: {
     name: 'Nominee name',
     phone: '9876546542',
     photo: File()
   }
}
```

### In Express

```js
app.post(upload.fields([{name:'photo'}, {name:'nominee'}]), function(req, res) {

    res.send(req.files['photo']);        // send file details

    res.send(req.files['nominee']);     // did not show any file details
}
```

---

#### OR

```js
app.post(upload.fields([{name:'photo'}, {name:'nominee.photo'}]), function(req, res) {

    res.send(req.files['photo']);             // send file details

    res.send(req.files['nominee.photo']);     // did not show any file details
}
```

In my express code i can access all file details for Parent Object but it did not show any details for child(nominee) Object. Is there anything wrong in my code or multer did not support nested child field..?

Comment: Maybe no `nominee` field is passed in the request content? Try logging the request or provide your html form code

Comment: @Crogo I have access all of the field from **Nominee** object except **photo** field in my express route.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a bit late but

```
upload.single('nominee[photo]')
```

Should do the job

Comment: What if `photo` is in an array of object?